# Force Maven Wagon plugin to POST instead of PUT

Tags: java, maven, http, maven-wagon-plugin

We're trying to use the Nexus APT plugin, but sending artifacts to it requires them to be POSTed not PUTed. The default Wagon implementation wants to HTTP Put it seems, because we're getting a 405 error back.

Is there a way to tell wagon to POST instead of PUT? I can't find it in the docs.

Thanks!

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>upload-deb-to-nexus</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>upload-single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <serverId>xxx-nexus-apt</serverId>
                                <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${jdeb.name}</fromFile>
                                <url>https://xxx.xxx.com/repository/xxx-nexus-apt</url>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: How do you know that it is a put method not the post, did you check in Fiddler ?

Comment: The docs say it's PUT. Because it's https I can't actually check the wire. If you use the maven-deploy-plugin it uses PUT by default as well

Comment: checked the server logs, wagon by default is a PUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the code for the Wagon http provider, `PUT` is hardcoded.